# Can not clone using Smart Git in Ubuntu

Tags: git, github, smartgit

I am using Smart Git to clone a Github repository on Ubuntu. But i am failing to clone it. It shows "Could not connect to the repository ...". I have used HTTPS and SSH both.

N.B: I have added hosting provider and it generated a Token.

[image]

Comment: your username is git? cool!

Comment: That is SSH URL... username is marked by red

Comment: `git clone` in command line is working?

Comment: did not try yet

Comment: i only installed smart git ... can i use command line git ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have found a solution, 
I have used '**Use OAuth token for repository authentication**'. Previously i was using '**Use SSH instead of HTTPS to access repositories**'

[image]